# « le conflit opposant les ouvriers de la mine de platine aux propriétaires de l'exploitation»

Tags: grammaire, phrase

La police sud-africaine intervient dans le conflit opposant les ouvriers de la mine de platine de Marikana, près de Johannesburg, aux propriétaires de l'exploitation.

Je suis dans l'embarras. Qu'est ce que "le conflit opposant les ouvriers" ici? "le conflit des ouvriers, qui oppose" ou "le conflit des ouvriers, qui opposent"? C'est quoi qui oppose ou opposent? "Le conflit" ou "les ouvriers"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ce qui oppose, c'est le conflit ; cela revient à dire que la situation de conflit concerne deux partis qui se trouvent opposés l'un à l'autre à cause de cette situation, ou dit autrement, le conflit fait s'affronter les deux partis (ouvriers contre propriétaires).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/opposer))
> **I.**
> **C.** − Opposer à
> […]
> **2.** [L'obj. désigne des pers.] **Mettre en face de quelqu'un, face à face pour un combat, une compétition**.
> ♦ Comment oseraient-ils me combattre seuls (...) N'eussent-ils que mille hommes à t'opposer, ils te les opposeraient (A. France,Voie glor., 1915, p.64).
> ♦ Abusant de la servitude militaire, ils vont jusqu'à nous opposer les poitrines de certaines troupes professionnelles (De Gaulle,Mém. guerre, 1954, p.422).
> − JEUX, SPORTS.
> ♦ Un débat entre l'Est et l'Ouest incarné par une partie d'échecs qui oppose deux champions qui sont aussi, de plus ou moins bon gré, champions de leurs systèmes politiques respectifs (Télérama,10 avr. 1985, p.29).
> **Faire s'affronter**.
> ♦ C'est là tout le sens du conflit qui oppose Ingres à Delacroix (Huyghe,Dialog. avec visible, 1955, p.206).

La sous-division de sens concernée dans cette définition est « faire s'affronter ». De façon synonyme, mais moins élégante, on pourrait écrire la phrase suivante.

- La police sud-africaine intervient dans le conflit **qui fait s'affronter** les ouvriers de la mine de platine de Marikana, près de Johannesburg, aux propriétaires de l'exploitation.

Comment: C'est le **B.** **2**.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, mais dans le **B.2.** c'est le cas particulier que j'indique ; la raison, c'est qu'il y a une nuance : il n'existe pas  une idée de combat ou de compétition organisés ; il se trouve que les circonstances de la vie amènent cette opposition. C'est généralement le cas pour les conflits ; d'ailleurs, remarquez bien l'exemple, qui est parallèle, jusqu'au point même de comprendre le mot  « conflit ». C'est à vous que je dois ce vote négatif ?

Answer (score 1):

La police sud-africaine intervient dans le conflit **opposant les ouvriers de la mine de platine de Marikana**, [près de Johannesburg], **aux propriétaires de l'exploitation**.

Il faut lire: le conflit opposant A à B [ici, aux propriétaires].

Un exemple d'actualité:

[image: Photo de l'ONU]

Réunion d'urgence du Conseil de sécurité de l'ONU sur **le conflit opposant la Russie à l'Ukraine** le 23 février 2022

afp.com/TIMOTHY A. CLARY

[L'EXPRESS](https://www.lexpress.fr/actualites/1/monde/l-onu-impuissante-a-empecher-une-guerre-de-la-russie-en-ukraine_2168672.html)